# get changing file within folder UploadFile button

Tags: c#, video, file-upload, youtube-api, var

So I have an upload file button which opens an open file dialog and lets you select a file.
Im not connected to server or db yet so just trying to send selected files to a specific folder on my c: drive, once the file is used it will be deleted so the name of the file will always be different.

when i want to send the file path to the method that will be using it is there a way to specify just the folder its in and for the system to use the only file within that folder then.

So far my code is all over the place as ive been trying to play around with it as im new to c# but this is what its lie so far(obviously the var isnt working and sch tried to use another example I found, getting 'not all code paths return a value error for 'getVideoFile'):

```
   public static  string getVideoFile (string filePath)
{
   var path= string;

    path = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\siobhan\Videos\FYPVids\");

    if (path != 0){
        return path;
    }
    else
    {
        //put in error message for no video file detected
    }


}
```

the button itself:
      protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (this.btnFileUpload.HasFile)
    {


        this.btnFileUpload.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\siobhan\Videos\FYPVids" + this.btnFileUpload.FileName);
    }
```

The method the file path needs to be sent to:

```
    var video = new Video();
    video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.Snippet.Title = vidDetails.vidTitle;
    video.Snippet.Description = vidDetails.vidDesc;
    video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "Test", "Second" };
    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "17";//category id for sport // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    video.Snippet.ChannelId = "UCfvR-wqeoHmAGrHnoQRfs9w";
    video.Status = new VideoStatus();
    video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; /2015\WebSites\FYP_November\IMG_6639.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.
```

Comment: Stop what you're doing, get CLR Via C#, and read it (skip the parts about the GC and other really technical chapters--save them for later).

Comment: if i had time i would but college project due in a couple days  really doesn't allow for that sort of reading!